# Вопрос по лексическому парсеру

Tags: парсер

Есть нескольно БНФ, определяющих грамматику некоего языка (допустим, языка Си).

Есть выражение, написанное на этом языке, к примеру

```
int t = 15;
```

Допустим, с помощью некоей конструкции, на некоем языке N, я получаю из входного потока (где записаны выражения на данном языке) токены, в данном случае:

```
string[] tokens = {"int", "t", "=", "15"};
```

Вопрос.
Как сие выражение, собственно, распарсить?
Брать первый токен, и идти по всем БНФ, в надежде найти ту БНФ, которая начинается с type-specifier? 
Но этот подход не уместен, ибо только БНФ задает, type-specifier ли данное выражение или нет. (type-specifier: int | void | char | short).

Положим даже больше - программа вообще не должна ничего знать и понимать о сущностях вроде *type-specififer*, *type-declarator* и т.п. - она тупо должна уметь проводить разбор входного потока на токены и возвращать в виде структур или еще как-то типы выражений.

Как этого достичь?

Comment: А халяву, собственно, никто не обещал. Либо state machine делать, либо... даже не знаю что сказать =) К тому же в данной ситуации нужно определить тип самого языка. БНФ БНФом, но LR и LL грамматики совсем по-разному разбираются.

Comment: Lr Ll имеете в виду Left recursive и Right recursive? Хм, ну что ж, почитаем почитаем...

Answer (score 1):

Первое что приходит на ум это полный перебор

Comment: та о тож, но сам понимаешь, у него время как бы O(n), с учетом рекурсивного парсинга под-БНФ и т.д. там вообще до O(n^4) вырастет

Comment: Можно придумать как оптимизировать БНФ, представить их в виде дерева и по нему ходить сопоставляя с узлами токены. Мысли вслух.

Comment: Ага, тоже такие мысли посещали голову